# Unicode Font Support - WinForms Label

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, internationalization, globalization

I have a WinForms label control that is reading data from a JSON object and setting the text property.

I have not found a font that properly supports certain glyphs.

I'm only dealing with European countries in my situation, so no Chinese or Japanese.

Here's an example of how it is rendering it in the label control:

[image: Swedish Rendering in Label]

However, when I open the JSON file in Visual Studio, rendering with Consolas, it appears fine:

[image: Correct Rendering - Swedish in Visual Studio]

Even if I set the label to Consolas font, it does not match what Visual Studio is showing.

What do I have to go about here to make the label properly render these glyphs?

Comment: Nothing to do with fonts, this is a text encoding problem.  It was encoded in utf-8 but for some reason it wasn't read that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HansPassant, I realized what the issue here was.

The JSON file in question was an embedded resource, and was set to `FileType.Binary`.

This was unnecessary, so I changed this to `FileType.Text`, which allows the `Encoding` property to be set.

With `Encoding` as *Unicode (UTF-8) - Codepage 65001*, this is now displaying as intended.